# jQuery Mobile Not Working (I only see Broken Bells)

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, wamp

I downloaded the jQuery Mobile Demo to see how query mobile works. I put the files in a folder called "test" and I put this test folder in the www folder of my WAMP server. When I try to open the webpage (Chrome, Firefox or IE) I dont see anything except for a Broken Bells written in the top left corner of the screen in blue test with a broken image. I have no idea what is going on. I have the same case when I try to run the webpage on my tablet (Sony Tablet S). Please help if you can. Thanks.

-----------------after edit-----------------------

Ok this is what I have tried now. I went to this page http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js. I copied the code from that page to a file called jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js. Then in the same folder as that file, I have another file called index.php. In that file I have this code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Anchor</a>
    <form>
        <button>Button</button>
        <input value="Input" type="button">
        <input value="Submit" type="submit">
        <input value="Reset" type="reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the page opens but the buttons do not as they should with jQuery and I do not understand why. Please help if you can.

Comment: What are the errors in your browser's console?

Comment: HTTP request failed for an unknown reason.

Comment: My assumption is your paths for including the files are incorrect, or not loading for some reason.  I would start with the CSS files (see if you can access them directly).  If you can, are they hosted remotely (outside of MAMP) or locally (on MAMP)?  If it's remote, it could be a firewall or configuration blocking the external files from loading.

Comment: I have created a new project and the code is pasted above in which you can see the paths. Please let me know if the paths are incorrect. If the firewall problem is happening how can I stop that without removing the firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you expected to see ? And what you trying to do with this code?

The Right way to include jquery mobile library:

```
<head>
  <link href="YOUR_FOLDER/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  <script src="YOUR_FOLDER/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="YOUR_FOLDER/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

First of all you need to include all the library files: .css & .js files.
Second of all there has to be a jquery include [not mobile] first (jquery-1.8.0.js or other version) and than jquery.mobile-x.x.x.js.
Jquery mobile library can't work without the jquery library....

Finally, after you included the files...
I don't understand what you trying to do with this code, but here is an example for you:

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Page content goes here.</p>  
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: Works! Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using data-ajax=disabled on every link and button if you are running on local host. I don't remember the syntax but I remember having a similar problem.